# Getting list of roles KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, roles

I try to use Keycloak in spring boot app. And want to check if there user's role in list of roles, something like this:

```java
 http.authorizeRequests(a-> a
                .antMatchers("/customers*", "/users*")
                .hasAnyRole(*/list of roles from kk realm/*)
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll());
```

If there any Opportunity in KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter? Beacuse now I can only checking roles using string and already known role:

```java
 http.authorizeRequests(a-> a
                .antMatchers("/customers*", "/users*")
                .hasAnyRole("role")
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll());
```

full code:

```java
@KeycloakConfiguration
class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // Submits the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider to the AuthenticationManager

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthorityMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
        grantedAuthorityMapper.setPrefix("ROLE_");

        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    // Specifies the session authentication strategy
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HttpSessionManager.class)
    protected HttpSessionManager httpSessionManager() {
        return new HttpSessionManager();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);

        http.authorizeRequests(a-> a
                .antMatchers("/customers*", "/users*")
                .hasAnyRole("roles")
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll());
    }
```

Comment: You want to read all the available roles from keycloak dynamically?

Comment: Something like that, I want to authorized user by checking if his role belong to list of roles in kk realm

Comment: To get a list of roles from the realm, you need to make a API call to Keycloak. Then replace the method call with hardcoded role. But that is not the purpose of hasAnyRole method. `hasAnyRole()` checks if the role you are passing is available for user in `Keycloak`. If you read all the available roles and pass to `hasAnyRole()` it will allow all the user's to all the endpoints

Comment: Realm can have n number of roles. But if you want to allow `/customer/**` only to the user who has a role `ROLE_CUSTOMER` then you must pass it in the application only